# Automatic completion search default value

Tags: javascript, angular, meteor

I'm trying to make an automatic completion search on a list on my application.
The search works quite well, but I can't display all the value of the list when the page is loaded.

For example, when I arrive on my search page, I want the content of my list to be displayed and when I'm doing a search I want the values filtered.
The filter works perfectly, but the "default display" doesn't seem to work.

Here is the code:

```
 itemList: Observable<Item[]>; //List displayed on the view
 term = new FormControl();
    ngOnInit() {
        //A search is done when the user type something in the search bar
        //then load on the list
       this.itemList = this.term.valueChanges
            .debounceTime(400)
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .switchMap(term => this.searchItem(term));
    }

    /**
    * Search of an item by a value.
    * If there is no value to search, load all item
    */
    searchItem(valueToSearch:string){
        var result;
        var userItemId;
        if(Meteor.user() !== undefined) {
            userItemId = Meteor.user().profile.ItemIds;
        }
        if(valueToSearch == ''){
                result = Items.find({'_id': {$nin: userItemId}});
        }
        else {
            var regexSearch = new RegExp(valueToSearch.toLowerCase(), "i");
            result = Items.find({'title': regexSearch, '_id': {$nin: userItemId}});
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Basically, I can't seem to make that part work when the page is loaded:

```
...         
if(valueToSearch == ''){
                result = Items.find({'_id': {$nin: userItemId}});
        }
...
```

Maybe it's a "subscribe" problem, I'm not very familiar with that functionality.

Comment: searchItem() should return an Observable

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't get it, what would it changes when the page load? I mean, when I'm doing a research, it works fine. Can you explain a bit more please :)

Comment: switchmap function takes a param and returns a stream . I will write an answer how I would do if I doing the same task.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Observable and return it. If Meteor returns promise you can directly create Observable.fromPromise() 
Hope it helps.

```
searchItem(valueToSearch:string): Observable<Item[]>{
    return Observable.create((observer)=>{
       let userItemId = Meteor.user() 
                && Meteor.user()
                && Meteor.user().profile
                && Meteor.user().profile.ItemIds;
   if(!userItemId){
       observer.error('');
   }
   if(valueToSearch == ''){
       observer.next(Items.find({'_id': {$nin: userItemId}}));
   }else {
        var regexSearch = new RegExp(valueToSearch.toLowerCase(), "i");
        observer.next(Items.find({'title': regexSearch,'_id': {$nin: userItemId}}));
    }

});
```